# Why the method in some class I created, ask me for input "self"?

Tags: python, class, oop, self

I am new in OO programming. It is python 3.
Let be some example code:

```
class MyClass:
      def __init__(self,a=1,b=2):
          self.a=a
          self.b=b
      def function1(self):
          c.self=salf.a/self.b + 5
          return(c.self)
```

When I call a method from MyClass. i.e:

```
MyClass.function1()
```

it returns:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

I understand that if I initialize the code as:

```
class MyClass(object):
     code etc...
```

It is all right if I put:
      `somevariable=MyClass; somevariable.function1()`

It works... I do not know why this is happening.

Thank you so much !

Comment: This would *not* raise a NameError...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object of your class:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self,a=1,b=2):
      self.a=a
      self.b=b
  def function1(self):
      self.c=self.a/self.b + 5
      return(self.c)

print(MyClass().function1())
```

`MyClass()` creates an object that can be used to access attributes in the class.

For a general instance:

```
m = MyClass()
print(m.function1())
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see where you create the instance.. at least it would be
`print(MyClass().function1())` In many codes you just have to put. `MyClass.function1()` or something

Comment: Show in code that `MyClass()` create an ***object*** and not just a placeholder for methods.

Comment: @EdmondGeraudAguilar please see my recent edit.

Comment: Which is the difference between class `Myclass(object): etc` and  ` class Myclass: etc ` ?

Comment: @EdmondGeraudAguilar  `Myclass(object): pass` is known as a new style class.  `Myclass(object)` is inheriting from `object`, the goal being to unify types and classes.

Comment: @EdmondGeraudAguilar in Python 3 there is no distinction.